# Does onTokenRefresh get called on app update?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Does InstanceIDListenerService#onTokenRefresh get called in all cases where a gcm token may have changed, like when an app gets updated, or gets restored from an auto-backup, etc? Or do I still have to worry about catching those types of things like in older versions of GCM?

Comment: I think that when you app updated equals the user reinstall your app, so they will get new GCM token from InstanceID `getToken()`. Then you can update it to your servicer accordingly.

Comment: I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412312/does-instance-id-service-initiate-callback-ontokenrefresh-on-app-upgrade). Please share anything which you found.

Comment: Not sure about GCM, but in the new Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), this is all taken care of for you for sure